# eigenvalues of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know when we change basis eigenvalues of linear transformation is invariant
But  i dont know when we use two basis.
When Linar trans formation domain use basis A  ans codomain use basis B. Are eigenvalues same as only one basis?

Answer (score 0):

A linear transformation has its eigenvalues that don't change when we change basis. We represent a linear transformation with a matrix with respect to some basis. As I said, this matrix will have the same eigenvalues regardless of what basis we use.

When you want to go from one basis to another, you use a change of basis matrix. It cannot happen that you "use two bases".

In order to get the right answer, try to clarify your question a bit more, perhaps.